# How do I get single-Enter execution with Oh My Zsh when using event designators?

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In plain zsh, when I press Enter, it runs the command I've typed. Hooray! This includes performing any necessary event designator substitutions all in one go, though it prints them out along the way:

```
~ % echo a b c # ^M
a b c
~ % echo !$ # ^M
echo c
c
~ % echo !-2:2 # ^M
echo b
b
~ %
```

I've decorated the above block with `# ^M` to indicate where I pressed the Enter key.

In contrast, with Oh My Zsh, when I hit Enter, it runs the command immediately but only if there are no event designator substitutions to be made. Other types of substitutions happen inline, but if I've used an event designator, instead of actually running the command, it gives me a new line with a new prompt and the substitution having been made. Example, same `# ^M` business as above:

```
~ % echo a b c # ^M
a b c
~ % echo !$ # ^M
~ % echo c # ^M
c
~ % echo !-2:2 # ^M
~ % echo b # ^M
b
~ % echo $(echo a b) c # ^M
a b c
~ %
```

Note that I have to hit Enter twice to make most of the commands run, though the final one with the `$()` substitution runs in a single go.

How do I configure OMZ to use the normal zsh behavior here, or otherwise just configure zsh to go back to normal after OMZ has performed its dark magic? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make zsh do this in the first place.

(I know that I can use the Tab key to have the substitution performed immediately. That's fine, but I know I typed the thing correctly and I just want it to run without seeing it again first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the option `HIST_VERIFY` is unset. Obviously it get's set somewhere in your config.

> HIST_VERIFY
> Whenever the user enters a line with history expansion, don't execute the line directly; instead, perform history expansion and reload the line into the editing buffer.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it - OMZ does `setopt hist_verify`. The language around the option (history) didn't match the language around the feature (event) so it was difficult to find the right documentation. Much appreciated.